# Hilbert Polynomial at a point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hilbert-polynomial

One of the review problems in my final review is the following:

> Let $X\subset\mathbb P_{\mathbb C}^n$ be a hypersurface, and $P\in X$ a singular point. Let $L$ be a line not contained in $X$ that intersects $X$ at $P$.
>
> Prove that $h_{X\cap L}(P)\geq2$, the intersection multiplicity of $X$ and $L$ at $P$, where $h_{X\cap L}(P)$ refers to the hilbert polynomial of $X\cap L$ at $P$.

From my readings, it doesn't seem like the hilbert polynomial accepts a point as input, but rather a natural number. So what does this even mean?

Comment: Hm yeah I am not sure that this makes sense? Not an expert though. Could they mean like intersection number of $X\cap L$ at $P$?

Comment: Oh it even says that in the question lol. Yeah I think the stuff after the semicolon is just a typo or they forgot to delete it or something.

Comment: @user113102 that seems like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a community wiki answer recording the discussion in the comments so that this question might be marked as answered (once this answer is upvoted or accepted).

> Hm yeah I am not sure that this makes sense? Not an expert though. Could they mean like intersection number of $X\cap L$ at $P$? – **user113102**
>
> Oh it even says that in the question lol. Yeah I think the stuff after the semicolon is just a typo or they forgot to delete it or something. – **user113102**

Comment: While interesting, I'm not sure this constitutes an answer. The problem most certainly refers to the Hilbert polynomial, so a proper answer in my opinion should address the correct way to view the problem in terms of a hilbert polynomial.

Comment: Your post closes with the line "So what does this even mean?", and the text enclosed in your post exactly tells you that they're using $h_{X\cap L}(P)$ to refer to the intersection number. I think this is precisely an answer to your question as written.

Comment: Right, but read the end of the question: it mentions evaluating the hilbert polynomial at $P$.